# Maven - use encrypted password for oracle OSB and SOA deployment

Tags: maven, soa, servicebus, osb

Our pom.xml for osb service refers to the maven settings.xml to get the server details and credentials for deployment.
pom.xml has below entries:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
    <groupId>com.oracle.servicebus.plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>oracle-servicebus-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>12.2.1-4-0</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <oracleHome>${oracleHome}</oracleHome>
        <oracleServerUrl>${oracleServerUrl}</oracleServerUrl>
        <oracleUsername>${oracleUsername}</oracleUsername>
        <oraclePassword>${oraclePassword}</oraclePassword>
    </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

settings.xml has got below entries:

```
<profile>
  <id>server-devb</id>
  <properties>
    <oracleHome>/oracle/apps/fusion/devb_soa_suite_12_2_1_4_0</oracleHome>
    <oracleServerUrl>http://esb-soa-server1-devb:7001</oracleServerUrl>
    <oracleSoaServerUrl>http://esb-soa-server1-devb:8001</oracleSoaServerUrl>
    <oracleServerT3>t3://esb-soa-server1-devb:7001</oracleServerT3>
    <oracleUsername>weblogic_buildserver</oracleUsername>
    <oraclePassword>{WhEa5AhivzUHwQHIv7oQHsbBjcA3e5jKuMpjTzPTbkZevhD9UUjr34NEY5ROPgEI} 
    </oraclePassword>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

If we keep the password in settings.xml as plaintext, the deployment works fine.
but if we encrypt it, it fails in user authentication while deployment.

we followed this guide for maven password encryption -
https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html#introduction

Comment: What do you mean by "it fails"?

Comment: we get below error:
java.lang.SecurityException: User failed to be authenticated.
 at weblogic.common.internal.RMIBootServiceImpl.authenticate(RMIBootServiceImpl.java:121)
 at weblogic.common.internal.RMIBootServiceImpl_WLSkel.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.invoke(BasicServerRef.java:645)
 at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef$2.run(BasicServerRef.java:534)
 at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedS

Comment: This password must be encrypted with WebLogic tooling and with the salt stored in your domain. 
The easiest way is to get the excrypted password from the boot.properties file which is under $DOMAIN_HOME/servers/AdminServer/security